# Redirecionamento com temporizador e identificador de uso do usuário

Tags: html, redirecionamento

A minha duvida é um pouco complexa:

Hoje eu utilizo um redirecionamento simples apenas usando HTML:

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='480;URL=./logout.php?type=2'>
```

Onde "CONTENT" é o tempo (em segundos) regressivo que ele contará antes de redirecionar. Mas eu uso esse código como um auto-logout. Como 480 segundos são 8 minutos, depois de 8 minutos sem uma alteração de pagina ou atualização o sistema irá "deslogar" automaticamente. Porem, tive que adicionar uma nova feature no sistema, onde agora é normal que ultrapassar esse tempo.

O que preciso de fato, é de alguma coisa (seja em JavaScript/ajax/PHP/html/Jquery) que zere o tempo caso o usuário esteja mexendo o mouse ou teclado(ou seja interagindo com a pagina) para que o sistema não feche no meio do trabalho.

Na minha cabeça isso é um bicho de sete cabeças, se alguém puder me ajudar... eu agradeço muito!

Comment: Eu acho que o ideal é você fazer esse controle no servidor-- invalidar a sessão depois de um certo tempo de inatividade.

Comment: Mas fazer isso não vai continuar com o mesmo problema não?

Comment: Esclareça, por favor, a frase "onde agora e normal que ultrapassar esse tempo"

Comment: ops Pablo, foi um erro de português meu:
"onde agora e normal que ultrapassar esse tempo"
na verdade é:
"onde agora é normal que ultrapassar esse tempo" (já corrigido)
caso sua duvida seja quanto a feature que adicionei, é um editor de texto, e isso fez com que o uso na mesma página ficasse bem maior fazendo com que vários usuários perdessem o texto, já que o sistema fechava só

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei como você controla o tempo de validade da sessão no servidor, então vou focar exclusivamente no cliente.

A ideia básica é usar a função 'setTimeout(function, tempoEmMilisegundos)' para "agendar" a chamada da função 'logoutFunction'. Nesta função eu uso o tempo da útlima interação com o sistema para decidir se o usuário será redirecionado para a página de logout ou se o redirecionamento será adiado.

Para salvar o tempo da última modificação foi criado uma função ('setLastModified') que simplesmente modifica a variável usada na comparação do tempo ('var lastModified'), depois a função é atribuida aos eventos 'onmousemove' e 'onkeypress' do html, assim toda vez que houver um movimento do mouse ou uma tecla for pressionada o tempo será atualizado.

```
(function(){
    var minutesToLogout = 8 * 60 * 1000; // Configure o tempo que achar melhor
    var logoutUrl = './logout.php?type=2'; // Configure a URL de logout

    var lastModified = Date.now();
    var html = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
    var setLastModified = function(){lastModified = Date.now();}

    html.onmousemove = setLastModified;
    html.onkeypress = setLastModified;

    var logoutFunction = function(){
        var timeDiff = Date.now() - lastModified;
        if(timeDiff > minutesToLogout)
            document.location = logoutUrl;
        else
            setTimeout(logoutFunction, minutesToLogout - timeDiff);
    }
    setTimeout(logoutFunction, minutesToLogout);
})();
```

Obs. A função setTimeout não é exata, ela pode ter um pequeno atraso em algumas circunstâncias, mas nada muito preocupante.

Comment: Cara, Erik, Muito obrigado mesmo, vou continuar tentando pois o código que vc passou não está funcionando 100%, quando estou preenchendo o formulário ele não detecta o keypress, mas funcionou perfeitamente para o mouse.
Não sou muito bom em JS(na verdade não sei nada de JS), posso ter me confundido em alguma coisa mas já serviu para direcionar... Vlw mesmo!!